# ABAP Websocket Server XSRF Token

Tags: sockets, abap

I'm currently trying to setup a web-socket server on an SAP application server as a proof of concept. The application which is connecting to the web-socket server is not going to be a UI5 or WebDynpro application but just a middle-ware program running on a headless computer.

Following a quick guide, I've setup the push channel and I have an object with the interface methods `ON_START`, `ON_MESSAGE` and etc. I'm currently testing the interface using `wscat` which you can get from `npm`.

When I tried connecting to my service for the first time using `wscat` I was receiving a HTTP 500 error.

[image]

I wasn't sure why I was getting the 500 error, so I tried to access the URL via http and a web browser to see what was happening.

```
500 SAP Internal Server Error

ERROR: Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF) check has failed ! (termination: ABORT_MESSAGE_STATE)
```

I had seen these tokens also in use by Gateway services, so I had created a quick gateway service and sent a `GET` request with `X-CSRF-Token: Fetch` except the token that I get from this doesn't work when I attempt to use uri parameter `sap-XSRF`.

Going forward, I started to debug `CL_APC_MANAGER` function `HANDLE_REQUEST` to see if my request comes in at all. I also wanted to trace where the origin of the 500 error comes from. I've managed to trace it back to `CL_APC_MANAGER` method `CHECK_XSRF`.

```
METHOD check_xsrf.
  DATA: lv_xsrf_token             TYPE string. 
  * 
  * validate XSRF token
  *
  lv_xsrf_token = i_server->request->get_form_field( name = if_http_form_fields_sap=>sap_xsrf ).
IF lv_xsrf_token IS INITIAL.
  lv_xsrf_token = i_server->request->get_header_field( name = if_http_form_fields_sap=>sap_xsrf ).
ENDIF.

IF lv_xsrf_token IS INITIAL.
  r_successful = abap_false.
ELSE.

  CALL METHOD i_server->validate_xsrf_token
    EXPORTING
      token                    = lv_xsrf_token
    IMPORTING
      successful               = r_successful
    EXCEPTIONS
      token_not_found          = 1
      cookie_not_found         = 2
      internal_error           = 3
      called_by_public_service = 4
      OTHERS                   = 5.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0 OR abap_false = r_successful.
    r_successful = abap_false.
  ELSE.
    r_successful = abap_true.
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.
```

If I skip this check manually with the debugger, than I'm able to connect to my web-socket server without a problem.

[image]

However I'm not sure at all how I'm actually supposed to get this token before attempting to connect. I noticed the `XSRF Tokens` are saved in database table `SECURITY_CONTEXT`. The only problem is an entry is created in this table with the key I need to have **after I attempt to connect**. I need it **before** and I'm not sure what the procedure is for retrieving a token properly.

Is there anybody with previous experience using these that can shed some light? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I'm using Version 740 with Service Pack 4.

Comment: To include, I ended up getting a bit impatient in my search and ended up writing a handler which retreives the token and injects it into a request, and then calls the standard SAP implementation: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c784568f69239ef722f However this isn't a real solution, it's just a hack.

Comment: Have you maintained the cross origin whitelist (transaction `SAPC_CROSS_ORIGIN`)?

Comment: I just tried, I don't seem to have that transaction.

Comment: What release and patch are your ABAP system - it should be there? Otherwise, try maintaining table  `APC_CROSS_ORIGIN` directly.

Comment: I also don't have that table. Release is 740 and EHP7.

Comment: Which patch level? I think websockets (ABAP Channels) were only released with 7.40 SP5 although the functionality was available since SP2. I'm guessing you may be on an older support pack? I've had a quick look and that table doesn't seem to be delivered in a note, in which case your workaround may be the only way.

Comment: Yea, that could be true. It's SP4. In which case, I guess the only option is my little workaround. Thanks! If you'd like credit for the answer you can post it as a response and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool, I've added it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to do have the header generated correctly is by maintaining table `APC_CROSS_ORIGIN` (transaction `SAPC_CROSS_ORIGIN`).

WebSockets functionality was only released for customer use in 7.40SP5, which probably explains why you don't have that table in your system. I'd recommend using your workaround for now, until your system has been patched.