# Cross origin issue of ABAP push channel

Tags: websocket, sapui5, abap

I just delevoped a demo with ABAP Push Channel and UI5. On the server side, the ABAP push channel tests well with WebDynpro app 'wdr_test_apc_wsp'. But when I integrated it with client, it cannot establish a connection. 
Here is the code that create web socket connection

```
        //establish websocket connection
        this.oWs = new SapPcpWebSocket("/sap/bc/apc/sap/ZQCHART_WS_GATEWAY", SapPcpWebSocket.SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS.v10); 

        //register callback functions on WebSocket Events
        this.oWs.attachOpen(function(e){
            console.log("connection created");
        });

        this.oWs.attachMessage(function(oEvent){
            //Message from server is coming in
            console.log(oEvent);
        });
```

Then I run this app on web ide, but the chrome got this error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://webidetesting3973187-fiori.dispatcher.neo.ondemand.com/sap/bc/apc/sap/ZQCHART_WS_GATEWAY' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501
```

The APC is on another SAP system.
I'm wondering if it's caused by cross origin policy, if so, what can I do with it?

Comment: did you establish the connection in neo-app.json / cloud-connector etc? are you able to connect to the same service regularly?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility - 
When creating the push channel in ABAP did you specify a protocol? On our version of NW there is a box for protocol which can either be blank or populated. If it is blank don't pass in the protocol when creating your websocket.

When running on the same box - the APC service URL is different from the BSP service URL.

Also came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983752/abap-websocket-server-xsrf-token?rq=1) which specifies another table related to cross site request.